# How to export (and consume) JSDoc comments in typescript NPM packages

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get comfortable writing consumable npm packages in typescript. I have a toy project up at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lynda-copy-course/, and the project organization is succeeding in:

- running from the command line after `npm install -g lynda-copy-course`
- working inside of another js/ts project after `npm install -s lynda-copy-course`
- making its type definitions known inside of projects that consume it from npm

The last sticking point is that consuming projects **aren't aware of the JSDoc style comments** that accompany the source classes and methods.

**How do I configure my project (`package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, etc) so that consuming packages can read my JSDoc comments?**

My current `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "lynda-copy-course",
  "version": "2.1.7",
  "bin": {
    "lynda-copy-course": "./bin/lynda-copy-course.js"
  },
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "types": "./src/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "inquirer": "^3.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

My current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "bin/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true
    }
}
```

Github repo at the time of this posting: [**here**](https://github.com/NiloCK/lynda-copy-course/tree/08dc0bbc757cf92ae3b371135d77465fe998ebc2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here was in my `tsconfig.json`. The `compilerOptions.removeComments = true` setting was preventing the JSDoc comments from being inserted into my generated `.d.ts` files.

For me, this was somewhat unexpected behavior. Related issue on Typescript's gh page: [Preserve JSDocs in *.d.ts files when stripping comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14619)

Comment: Thanks for this, this resolved mine, especially when trying to consume it from npm. I'm having all jsDoc available now for interface inheritance. God bless you